# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) http://localhost:5000/api/refresh_token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Im getting this error, but I don't know what's wrong with my code, since it works perfectly on Postman, but doesn't when I run it on Node.js or localhost:3000 (which is my client side).

Here's the controller authCtrl.js code:

```js
const Users = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const authCtrl = {
  register: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { fullname, username, email, password, gender } = req.body;
      let newUserName = username.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "");

      const user_name = await Users.findOne({ username: newUserName });
      if (user_name)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This user name already exists." });

      const user_email = await Users.findOne({ email });
      if (user_email)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This email already exists." });

      if (password.length < 6)
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ msg: "Password must be at least 6 characters." });

      const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

      const newUser = new Users({
        fullname,
        username: newUserName,
        email,
        password: passwordHash,
        gender,
      });

      const access_token = createAccessToken({ id: newUser._id });
      const refresh_token = createRefreshToken({ id: newUser._id });

      res.cookie("refreshtoken", refresh_token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "http://localhost:5000/api/refresh_token",
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30days
      });

      await newUser.save();

      res.json({
        msg: "Register Success!",
        access_token,
        user: {
          ...newUser._doc,
          password: "",
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  },
  login: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      const user = await Users.findOne({ email }).populate(
        "followers following",
        "avatar username fullname followers following"
      );

      if (!user)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This email does not exist." });

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Password is incorrect." });

      const access_token = createAccessToken({ id: user._id });
      const refresh_token = createRefreshToken({ id: user._id });

      res.cookie("refreshtoken", refresh_token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "http://localhost:5000/api/refresh_token",
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30days
      });

      res.json({
        msg: "Login Success!",
        access_token,
        user: {
          ...user._doc,
          password: "",
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  },
  logout: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      res.clearCookie("refreshtoken", {
        path: "http:/localhost:5000/api/refresh_token",
      });
      return res.json({ msg: "Logged out!" });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  },
  generateAccessToken: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken;
      if (!rf_token)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Refresh token failed." });

      jwt.verify(
        rf_token,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        async (err, result) => {
          if (err) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "JWT Verify failed." });

          const user = await Users.findById(result.id)
            .select("-password")
            .populate(
              "followers following",
              "avatar username fullname followers following"
            );

          if (!user)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "This does not exist." });

          const access_token = createAccessToken({ id: result.id });

          res.json({
            access_token,
            user,
          });
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  },
};

const createAccessToken = (payload) => {
  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "1d",
  });
};

const createRefreshToken = (payload) => {
  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });
};

module.exports = authCtrl;
```

Here's the util fetchData.js (where I use axios to fetch the data):

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const getDataAPI = async (url, token) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const postDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const putDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const patchDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const deleteDataAPI = async (url, token) => {
  const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/${url}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};
```

Here's the redux action authAction.js file:

```js
import { GLOBALTYPES } from "./globalTypes";
import { postDataAPI } from "../../utils/fetchData";

export const login = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT, payload: { loading: true } });
    const res = await postDataAPI("login", data);
    dispatch({
      type: GLOBALTYPES.AUTH,
      payload: {
        token: res.data.access_token,
        user: res.data.user,
      },
    });

    localStorage.setItem("firstLogin", true);
    dispatch({
      type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT,
      payload: {
        success: res.data.msg,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT,
      payload: {
        error: err.response.data.msg,
      },
    });
  }
};

export const refreshToken = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem("firstLogin");
  if (firstLogin) {
    dispatch({ type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT, payload: { loading: true } });
    try {
      const res = await postDataAPI("refresh_token");
      dispatch({
        type: GLOBALTYPES.AUTH,
        payload: {
          token: res.data.access_token,
          user: res.data.user,
        },
      });
      dispatch({ type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT, payload: {} });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT,
        payload: {
          error: err.response.data.msg,
        },
      });
    }
  }
};
```